# Find first occurrence of part of a string after another identified string

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to write a fairly complex condition. I'll explain in this example:

```
<document>
  <para>
     <wd>Hello</wd>
     <wd>Stackoverflow</wd>
  </para>
  <para>
     <run>
        <wd> PO23135153 </wd>
        <wd> text and numb3rs </wd>
        <wd> 312.000 </wd>
        <wd> moar stuff </wd>
     </run>
     <wd> PO3213213 </wd>
     <wd> blah </wd>
     <wd> 1000.000 </wd>
     <wd> 000.000 </wd>
   </para>
 </document>
```

What I need to do is pick out the 1000.000 and 312.000

I believe this can be done by finding the *first* string that contains ".000", after a string that contains "PO*" is found.

The structure of the XML document can vary, and so can the number of instances of POs and the associated .000s

I believe that this can be achieved, in part, using "position()" and "contains" in an if expression, but I can't really bring it together.

Thanks for your help

EDIT

This more closely represents the XML data I have:

```
   <document>
  <para>
     <wd>Hello</wd>
     <wd>Stackoverflow</wd>
  </para>
  <para>
     <ln>
     <run>
        <wd> PO23135153 </wd>
     </run>
     <run>
        <wd> text and numb3rs </wd>
     </run>
     <run>
        <wd> 312.000 </wd>
     </run>
     <run>
        <wd> moar stuff </wd>
     </ln>
     <ln>
     </abc>
         <wd> PO3213213 </wd>
     </abc>
     <abc>
         <wd> blah </wd>
     </abc>
     <abc>
        <wd> 1000.000 </wd>
     </abc>
     <abc>
        <wd> 000.000 </wd>
     </abc>
     </ln>
   </para>
 </document>
```

Comment: You've asked a few questions so far - so you know that you are expected to try this yourself and post your code. Even if it did not work. That's precisely the point of posting here. Thanks!

Comment: The reason you are asked to supply code is so that others can copy it and use it for testing. When you post an invalid XML input, that becomes impossible - and one hesitates between wasting time correcting it or spending the time berating you for it. I believe Mathias' answer should still hold after replacing `following-sibling` with `following` - but that's only a superficial impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the wanted `wd` elements. It first matches `wd` if "PO" is contained in the element content and outputs this in `part_a` of the result. Then, this line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::wd[contains(.,'.000')][1]"/>
```

finds the first following `wd` element that is a sibling and contains ".000". The restriction `[1]` is necessary because otherwise "000.000" is output as well in your example.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="wd[contains(.,'PO')]">
  <result>
     <part_a>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </part_a>
     <part_b>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::wd[contains(.,'.000')][1]"/>
     </part_b>
  </result>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="wd"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <part_a> PO23135153 </part_a>
  <part_b> 312.000 </part_b>
</result>
<result>
  <part_a> PO3213213 </part_a>
  <part_b> 1000.000 </part_b>
</result>
```

Your elements contain trailing whitespace. You might want to prevent this in your output by using `normalize-space()`.

**EDIT**:

After changing the requirements, this is a sensible way to do it. Define a variable to store `wd` no matter where they occur in the tree. Then, iterate through them. The change of axes as suggested by **@michael.hor257k**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="wds" select="//wd"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="$wds">
     <xsl:if test="contains(.,'PO')">
        <result>
           <part_a>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </part_a>
           <part_b>
              <xsl:value-of select="following::wd[contains(.,'.000')][1]"/>
           </part_b>
        </result>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But first, you need to correct your updated XML input, which is invalid.

Be aware that this is the last time I update this answer. I am not willing to spend more time on this. Please say clearly what your input XML looks like *beforehand*.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I've just realised though that the PO and .000 values aren't actually siblings, they're cousins, if you will. IE They have a common grandparent ("ln")
I've tried using 

     `<xsl:value-of select="."/>
     <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ln[1]::ss:wd[contains(.,'.000')][1]"/>`

But that does not seem to work

Comment: @Dan Please edit your question so that it shows the *relevant* input.

Answer (score -1):

Break down you problem into parts and you'll get your result.

For what I understood, what you need is to find and element who has, in its first `<wd>` child, the 'PO' and has another `<wd>` child with '.000'

So, for the first part of your expression:

```
//*[./wd[position()=1 and contains(text(), 'PO')]]
```

And for the second part:

```
//*[./wd[contains(text(), '.000')]
```

No you have to combine the two, with:

```
//*[./wd[contains(text(), '.000')] and ./wd[position()=1 and contains(text(), 'PO')]]
```

This will return the nodes:

```
/document/para
/document/para/run
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, thanks though. I'll have a go at seeing if I can manipulate this for what I want and I'll post back here :)

Comment: This is not helpful, really and not a very in-the-spirit-of-XSLT way. Better use axes like following-sibling.

Comment: @MathiasMüller don't agree with the -1, you introduced the xslt transformation when Dan asked to "pick out" which is xpath and either Dan didn't explain correctly or your solution is not correct since, the main subject is the .000 no the "PO", so you can actually have a template that matches a PO that doesn't have a sibling with .000. Also in your case you'll only match the /document/para once, when in fact it has two .000 (the main subject of the question). Thank you

Comment: Only the first occurrence of ".000" should be output. Also, it is not correct that my solution matches /document/para once. I am matching `wd` elements, regardless of where in the tree they are. Could it be that you mistake XSLT for Xpath? My answer gives the correct answer for the input Dan has shown at first. But of course, changing the requirements also changes the solution.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, You're right about the "only the first ocurrence". About the second part, you're only matching the `<wd>PO...` having or not .000 siblings => `wd[contains(.,'PO')]` am I not interpreting correctly?